# Features lost when creating "Local copy for editing"

Tags: arcgis-10.2, editing, arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, feature-service

I want to edit a hosted feature service from AGOL (no server). I followed the steps to create a local copy for editing, however when I do this - not all of the features exist in the local copy. I cannot check to see if there are any errors or messages since it was not a geoprocess.  Does anyone know why this could be happening and how to resolve this issue? It happened multiple times.

STR:

1. Sign into AGOL from ArcMap
2. Add hosted feature service to map (drag and drop from Catalog)
3. Navigate to service in TOC (Listed by drawing order)
4. Right click, editing, create local copy for editing
5. Open attribute table for one layer... Holds 20 features, when it should have 68

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Report form Esri technical support: No features are actually lost. This appears to be a bug, but instead it is a part of the design. To increase efficiency and performance, the local map only caches to your current view extent.